# access website within android code and retrieve a generated image

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, android-widget

This description was very hard to word.  Basically I want to know if it is possible to access a website inside Android coding without actually sending the user to that website.

What I want to do is use a free website that generates a random pic after you upload your picture to it.  I want the user to be able to upload their selected image to the website, and I guess somehow in code make that website generate an edited image and retrieve it back into the application for further use.

I know this sounds really ridiculous but I just wanted to know if this was at all possible before I try writing the code.  Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible to upload and retrieve usually one needs an httpclient or there're can be exceptions like in the case described in the post http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is do an HTTP post upload of your image, as outlined here:

[Upload image](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

Then you can do your processing on the server side - you didn't specify which platform you are planning to use on the server side, but in PHP you might want to look at this:

[HTTP POST file upload](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Finally, you'll want to retrieve the resultant image you made available on the server side this way:

[Retrieve image from an URL](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device)

Comment: Thanks guys & @SergeyBenner.  I'm really new to android development but I have some ideas for apps and this will definitely help me start it!