# What is the best way to send an image from Android device to a server for processing and send the results back?

Tags: java, php, android, matlab, image-processing

Which kind of server-side image processing implementation would be convenient?
I would specifically want to know if this would be feasible using Java or PHP?

Also, if I have MATLAB installed on the server, is there any way I could make the Android device send the image to the server running Java (or PHP) code, and then make the Java (or PHP) code execute the MATLAB scripts and then communicate back the results from there?

Thanks for looking in.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem, or are you just looking for general information? If it's the former, that doesn't come through in your question so you may want to re-write it. If the latter, that isn't really what SO is well suited to, since there is no single correct answer.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9546917/80724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it like this:

- Upload the image (using [Apache Http libraries](http://hc.apache.org/)) using a `FileEntity` as part of a `MultipartEntity` as part of a `HttpPost`.
- Server **does not** block on this post and returns immediately. You could carry out processing on a background thread on the server.
- Server passes a [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) message upon completion with the location of the processed image.
- Client downloads the processed image.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your image bytes to outputstream in android and receive that at server side and do what you want to do with the image, through your scripts.